# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object when updating

Tags: php, mysql

This is driving me crazy ... hoping someone can point out what I am missing here.

I have a mysql table which holds client enquiries, each enquiry can hold multiple issues.
I want it so that an enquiry cannot be closed if there are any open issues.

To do this I am using an if statement to check the posted value of the status , if this is set to close, I do a COUNT .. if any results are OPEN, then show an error , else proceed with the update.

I am getting the following error however - Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

I have tried echoing each variable instead of updating and they all show correctly.

here is the code

```
$id=$_SESSION['SESS_ENQID'];

$enqdate=$_POST['enqdate'];
$enqsrc=$_POST['enqsrc'];
$notes=$_POST['notes'];
$enqstat=$_POST['enqstat'];

if($enqstat == 'CLOSED'){
$qry1 = "SELECT COUNT(*)FROM enqissuetbl WHERE enqstat = 'OPEN' AND enqid = ?"; 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry1);
$stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($count);
$stmt->fetch();

if($count >= '1')
{
printf("ERROR: All associated issues must be in a closed state before you can close an enquiry");
}
elseif($count == '0')
{
$qry2 = "UPDATE enqtbl 
SET enqdate = ?, enqsrc = ?, notes = ?, enqstat = ?
WHERE enqtbl.enqid = ? ";

$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($qry2);
$stmt2->bind_param('ssssi', $enqdate, $enqsrc, $notes, $enqstat, $id);

$stmt2->execute();
$stmt2->close();

printf("Enquiry successfully updated.");
unset($_SESSION['SESS_ENQID']); 
}
}
```

Comment: There are so many "Related" questions in the sidebar... At least half of them will have the same answer as yours. Please do some searching before asking a question.

Comment: I have been going through them but unable to spot my problem , whats throwing me is I use the same update code (exactly) after the above, if the $enstat is not equal to close ... as in , a user is updating the record but not closing it. That works perfectly , and its the exact same code that is failing above.

Comment: Did you consult the PHP manual? It states that `prepare` returns `false` if an error occurs during query preparation, and it provides an example of how to see the actual error: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out , both queries where fine on their own, the issue only occurred because they where nested ... adding $stmt->store_result(); to the outer query solved it.